# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `suggestDB` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

Hey so I have this error in my Schema and I don't know how to fix it. I also tried looking at the other files, but couldn't find any issue. Can someone help me fix this issue, please? I would really be appreciated.

There are 5 different suggestion files I have made

Schema 1:

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

module.exports = model("suggestDB", new Schema({
    GuildID: String,
    MessageID: String,
    Details: Array,
    MemberID: String,
    DM: Boolean,
}));
```

Schema 2:

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

module.exports = model("suggestSetupDB", new Schema({
    GuildID: String,
    ChannelID: String,
}))
```

suggest.js file:

```
const { CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const suggestDB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/suggestDB"); 
const suggestSetupDB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/suggestSetupDB"); 

module.exports = {
  name: "suggest",
  description: "Create a suggestion.",
  usage: "/suggest",
  disabled: false,
  botCommandChannelOnly: true,
  options: [
    {
      name: "type",
      description: "Select a type.",
      required: true,
      type: "STRING",
      choices: [
        {
          name: "Command",
          value: "Command",
        },
        {
          name: "Event",
          value: "Event",
        },
        {
          name: "System",
          value: "System",
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          value: "Other",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "suggestion",
      description: "Describe your suggestion.",
      type: "STRING",
      required: true,
    },
    {
      name: "dm",
      description: "Set whether the bot will DM you, once your suggestion has been declined or accepted.",
      type: "BOOLEAN",
      required: true,
    }
  ],
  /**
   *
   * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
   */
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const { options, guildId, member, user } = interaction;

    const suggestionsSetup = await suggestSetupDB.findOne({ GuildID: guildId });
    var suggestionsChannel;

    if(!suggestionsSetup) {
      return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ This server has not setup the suggestion system.`)]})
    } else {
      suggestionsChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(suggestionsSetup.ChannelID)
    }

    const type = options.getString("type");
    const suggestion = options.getString("suggestion");
    const DM = options.getBoolean("dm")
    
    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(system_embed_colour)
      .setAuthor({name: `${user.tag}`, iconURL: `${user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})}`}, )
      .setDescription(`**Suggestion:**\n${suggestion}`)
      .addFields(
        {name: "Type", value: type, inline: true},
        {name: "Status", value: " Pending", inline: true},
        {name: "Reason", value: "Pending", inline: true},
      )

    try {
      const M = await suggestionsChannel.send({embeds: [Embed]});
      
      M.react("");
      M.react("");

      await suggestDB.create({GuildID: guildId, MessageID: M.id, Details: [
        {
          MemberID: member.id,
          Type: type,
          Suggestion: suggestion,
        }],
        MemberID: member.id,
        DM: DM
      })
      interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor(system_embed_colour).setDescription(`✅ Your [suggestion](${M.url}) was successfully created and sent to ${suggestionsChannel}`).setFooter({text: "This system was created by M4HD1#6336"})], ephemeral: true})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ An error occured.`)]}) 
    }
  }
}
```

suggest-setup file:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message, CommandInteraction, Client } = require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/suggestSetupDB"); 
module.exports = {
  name: "suggest-setup",
  description: "Set up the channel to where suggestions are sent.",
  usage: "/suggest-setup",
  permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
  options: [
    {
        name: "set",
        description: "Set the channel where suggestions will be sent.",
        type: "SUB_COMMAND",
        options: [
            {name: "channel", description: "The channel where suggestions will be sent.", type: "CHANNEL", channelTypes: ["GUILD_TEXT"], required: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "current-channel",
        description: "Display the current suggestions channel.",
        type: "SUB_COMMAND",
      },
  ],
  /**
   *
   * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
   * @param {Client} client
   */
  async execute(interaction, client) {

    switch(interaction.options.getSubcommand()) {
        case "set":
            const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("channel");

            try {
                await channel.send({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("AQUA").setDescription(`✅ This channel has been set as a suggestions channel.`)]}).then(async() => {
                    await DB.findOneAndUpdate({GuildID: interaction.guild.id}, {ChannelID: channel.id}, {new: true, upsert: true})
                    interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor(admin_embed_colour).setDescription(`✅ ${channel} has successfully been set as the suggestions channel for ${interaction.guild.name}.`)]})
                })
            } catch (error) {
                if(error.message === "Missing Access") {
                    return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ The bot does not have access to this channel.`)]})
                } else {
                    return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`${client.emojisObj.animated_cross} An error occured. \n\n \`\`\`${error}\`\`\``).setFooter({text: "This system was created by M4HD1#6336"})]})
                }    
            }
        break;
        case "current-channel":
            const suggestion = await DB.findOne({GuildID: interaction.guild.id})

            if(!suggestion)
                return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌  This server has not setup the suggestion system.`)]})

            return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("AQUA").setDescription(`The suggestions channel is currently set to <#${suggestion.ChannelID}>`)]})
        break;
    }


  },
};
```

suggestion.js:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message, CommandInteraction, Client } = require("discord.js");
const suggestSetupDB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/suggestSetupDB"); 
const suggestDB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/suggestDB"); 

module.exports = {
  name: "suggestion",
  description: "Set up the channel to where suggestions are sent.",
  usage: "/suggestion",
  permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
  options: [
    {
      name: "accept",
      description: "Accept a suggestion.",
      type: "SUB_COMMAND",
      options: [
        {name: "message-id", description: "The message id of the suggestion you want to accept.", type: "STRING", required: true},
        {name: "reason", description: "The reason why this suggestion was accepted.", type: "STRING", required: true}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "decline",
      description: "Decline a suggestion.",
      type: "SUB_COMMAND",
      options: [
        {name: "message-id", description: "The message id of the suggestion you want to decline.", type: "STRING", required: true},
        {name: "reason", description: "The reason why this suggestion was declined.", type: "STRING", required: true}
      ]
    },
  ],
  /**
   *
   * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
   * @param {Client} client
   */
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const messageId = interaction.options.getString("message-id");
    const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason");

    const suggestionsSetup = await suggestSetupDB.findOne({ GuildID: interaction.guildId });
    var suggestionsChannel;

    if(!suggestionsSetup) {
      return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ This server has not setup the suggestion system.`)]})
    } else {
      suggestionsChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(suggestionsSetup.ChannelID)
    }

    const suggestion = await suggestDB.findOne({GuildID: interaction.guild.id, MessageID: messageId})

    if(!suggestion)
      return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ This suggestion was not found in the database.`)]})

    const message = await suggestionsChannel.messages.fetch(messageId)

    if(!message)
      return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`❌ This message was not found.`)]})

    const Embed = message.embeds[0];
    if(!Embed) return;
    
    switch(interaction.options.getSubcommand()) {
      case "accept":
        Embed.fields[1] = {name: "Status", value: "Accepted", inline: true};
        Embed.fields[2] = {name: "Reason", value: `${reason}`, inline: true}
        message.edit({embeds: [Embed.setColor("GREEN")], content: `<@${suggestion.MemberID}>`});

        if(suggestion.DM) {
          const member = client.users.cache.get(suggestion.MemberID);
          member.send({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setTitle("Suggestion ").setDescription(`Your suggestion was accepted ✅`).addFields({name: "Suggestion", value: `[link](${message.url})`, inline: true}, {name: "Guild", value: `${interaction.guild.name}`, inline: true}, {name: "Reason", value: `${reason}`, inline: true})]}).catch(() => null)
        }
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("AQUA").setDescription(`[Suggestion](${message.url}) was accepted ✅`)], ephemeral: true})
      break;

      case "decline":
        Embed.fields[1] = {name: "Status", value: "Declined", inline: true};
        Embed.fields[2] = {name: "Reason", value: `${reason}`, inline: true}
        message.edit({embeds: [Embed.setColor("RED")], content: `<@${suggestion.MemberID}>`});

        if(suggestion.DM) {
          const member = client.users.cache.get(suggestion.MemberID);
          member.send({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setTitle("Suggestion ").setDescription(`Your suggestion was declined. ✅`).addFields({name: "Suggestion", value: `[link](${message.url})`, inline: true}, {name: "Guild", value: `${interaction.guild.name}`, inline: true}, {name: "Reason", value: `${reason}`, inline: true})]}).catch(() => null)
        }
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("AQUA").setDescription(`[Suggestion](${message.url}) declined ✅`)], ephemeral: true})
      break;
    }
  },
};
```

And this is the error I get:

```
/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:505
      throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
            ^

OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `suggestDB` model once compiled.
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:505:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Structures/Schemas/suggestDB.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Commands/Moderation/suggest.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
```

Can someone help me find the issue in here?

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
const { model, Schema, models } = require('mongoose');
module.exports = models.suggestDB || model("suggestDB", new Schema({
GuildID: String,
MessageID: String,
Details: Array,
MemberID: String,
DM: Boolean,
}));
```

faced this error in nextjs.
Hope This Helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).